# I can't restart my audio file

Tags: javascript, audio, refresh, restart, piano

I am trying to make a piano on my website and for some reason, whenever I click on a note twice, the second time always seems to continue on from the first time (assuming that I don't hold it for the full length of the audio file). How do I make it so that when I click on a note more than once, the audio file restarts every time (keep in mind that I'm new to JavaScript).

```js
var C3 = new Audio();
C3.src = "assets/music/C3.mp3";
```

```css
div.w{
 height: 282px;
 width: 59px;
    position: absolute;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:3px;
}

div.b{
 height: 141px;
 width: 29.5px;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="w" id="C3" type="button" 
onmousedown="C3.play();document.getElementById('C3').style.backgroundColor='#cecece'"
onmouseup="C3.pause();document.getElementById('C3').style.backgroundColor='#ffffff'" 
onmouseleave="C3.pause();document.getElementById('C3').style.backgroundColor='#ffffff'">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with the Audio object myself, but it looks like it's because yo're pausing the audio and not then returning to the start. Perhaps this link may be of help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/fastSeek I think you need to pause the audio and then fastSeek to 0.

Comment: Sooo did that fix your issue @DylanCatterall

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the `currentTime` to `0`:

```js
var C3 = new Audio();
C3.src = "http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.oga";
```

```css
div.w{
 height: 282px;
 width: 59px;
    position: absolute;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:3px;
}

div.b{
 height: 141px;
 width: 29.5px;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="w" id="C3" type="button" 
onmousedown="C3.play();document.getElementById('C3').style.backgroundColor='#cecece'"
onmouseup="C3.pause();C3.currentTime = 0;document.getElementById('C3').style.backgroundColor='#ffffff'"
>
</div>
```